# How to create more than 256 /dev/loops?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to create more than 256 /dev/loops?

Comment: I'm curious: what do you need that many loop devices for??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to duplicate the loop driver and use a different name and a different major number.  That would give you another 256 each time you do that.  You'd likely need to be pretty comfortable with at least modifying kernel modules to pull that off.